# Calling array method in main class

Tags: arrays, methods

How can i call runningSum method in main with new array of intigers so it return result?

```
class Main {
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
        
    }

    public int[] runningSum(int[] nums) {
        int[] result = new int[nums.length];
        result[0] = nums[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
            result[i] = result[i - 1] + nums[i];
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add static modifier to your runningSum method. example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {



int[] myNum = {10, 20, 30, 40};

    int[] result = runningSum(myNum);

    for (int item : result){
        System.out.println(item);
    }


}

public static int[] runningSum(int[] nums) {
    int[] result = new int[nums.length];
    result[0] = nums[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
        result[i] = result[i - 1] + nums[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can we write this in a faster way, so i don't have to write a[0] = 5, a[1] = 6? Is declaring an array like this possible? int[]a = new int[]{1,1,1,1,1}

Comment: yes you can try this    int[] myNum = {10, 20, 30, 40};

Comment: and if my answer is help to you don't forget to vote my dear..

Comment: its not working :( your solution doesnt pring it out

Comment: can you explain me to what do you want to do in runningSum method

Comment: Given an array nums. We define a running sum of an array as runningSum[i] = sum(nums[0]…nums[i]).

Return the running sum of nums.

Comment: Input: nums = [1,1,1,1,1]
Output: [1,2,3,4,5]
Explanation: Running sum is obtained as follows: [1, 1+1, 1+1+1, 1+1+1+1, 1+1+1+1+1].

Comment: in this code it happen. wait i will edit the answer

Comment: It's pleasure to hear that. You can accept my answer and vote it.